# Save and restore instance state of an Activity manually

Tags: android, android-activity, persistence

I have a download activity in my app, where users can download some content. The activity is called from the main activity, and retrieves the list of available files to download over the network.

To avoid fetching the whole list again when the download activity is recreated e.g. because of rotation, I override `onSaveInstanceState()` to store the list in a `Bundle` and evaluate the `Bundle` passed to the `onCreate()` method. That works well for rotation.

However, I would like to be able to implement the same behavior if the user hits Back and later returns to the download activity. Android in this case does not call `onSaveInstanceState()`, hence nothing gets saved.

My idea was to override `onBackPressed()` and include a call to `onSaveInstanceState()`.

- Will this work at all?
- Can I just do `onSaveInstanceState(new Bundle())`, or do I have to initialize the new bundle somehow?
- Will Android store the bundle and pass it to `onCreate()` for the next instance of the Activity it creates, or do I have to take care myself of storing the `Bundle` and passing it to the new instance (if so, how)?

**UPDATE:**

Simply adding

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    onSaveInstanceState(new Bundle());
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

gives me the following exception:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState

for the call to `onBackPressed()`. (Swapping the two lines does nothing, presumably because there is nothing left to save.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally came up with the solution described below.

A word on usage: this will keep the state of the download activity in main memory, where it will occupy space. Also, Android may kill a background app at any time, typically if it runs low on memory. If that happens, the state information will be lost.

For my particular use case I decided I could live with these limitations: the state information written by my app is in the kilobyte range, and if the state information is lost, it can be recreated (it just takes time to fetch the list from the server). YMMV.

In the `onStop()` method of the download activity, do:

```
Bundle outState = new Bundle();
this.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
```

Store `outState` in a place where it can be retrieved when needed. In my case, the `BroadcastReceiver` which processes the download manager events was the place to put it.

To bring up the Activity from the `BroadcastReceiver`, do the following:

```
Intent downloadIntent = new Intent(context, DownloadActivity.class);
downloadIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
downloadIntent.putExtra("savedInstanceState", savedInstanceState);
context.startActivity(downloadIntent);
```

In the `onCreate()` method of the download activity, do:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Bundle state = savedInstanceState;
    if (state == null)
        state = this.getIntent().getBundleExtra(Const.KEY_SAVED_INSTANCE_STATE);
    super.onCreate(state);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> Will this work at all?

No.

> Will Android store the bundle and pass it to onCreate() for the next instance of the Activity it creates

No.

> do I have to take care myself of storing the Bundle and passing it to the new instance (if so, how)?

No.

Store your model data in a file or database, with a process-level cache (e.g., a custom singleton) to minimize disk I/O. Load your data out of the cache where available, or reload it from disk if needed.

Comment: Thanks for the insight – however, file or DB storage doesn't lend itself well to my particular situation. It would involve quite some code overhead, and I intend to keep the instance state only as long as there are still downloads in progress. I'm therefore leaning towards moving my bundle output/input logic into separate methods (which `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onCreate()` would call) and using these to store a `Bundle` when the user hits Back, and to restore the state of the previous instance.

Comment: @user149408: Presumably, you have a service doing these downloads. If you only want the data when the service is doing these downloads, then the service should hold the data, supplying it to the activities as needed.

Comment: I rely on `DownloadManager` for the downloads and already use the data it provides. The instance state is essentially the state of a helper class for a view component. It's not a lot of data (metadata for a directory tree, unlikely to ever exceed 300 kiB, probably around 10 kiB in most cases) but requires a bunch of network requests to rebuild from scratch.

Comment: @user149408: That doesn't meant that instance state is the right solution. After all, there's no guarantee that `DownloadManager` will be done quickly. Instance state is only good for ~30 minutes after your app is no longer in the foreground.

Comment: are you referring to the app potentially getting killed after some time in the background, possibly before the downloads finish?

Comment: @user149408: Yes. Configuration changes are a secondary use of instance state, as there are other solutions for that (e.g., retained fragment). The primary use of instance state is to be able to restore the UI if the app moves to the background, Android kills its process, but the user returns to it soonish (within ~30 minutes). On Android 5.0+, you might be able to use the `PersistableBundle` flavors of `onCreate()` and `onSaveInstanceState()` to handle periods beyond 30 minutes -- I haven't played with that scenario.